# How do I write my protractor scenarios to assert on http response errors?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm using protractor to test my angular client (server is built using Python Google App Engine).

I would like my protractor test to have an assertion on the http response from a POST that is triggered by clicking on a form button... like so:

```
  describe('Pointless Form Post Test', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('/myform'); 
  });

  it('should successfully populate a form, post it, and not return error', function() {
      element(by.model('form_summary')).sendKeys('Some input text');
      element(by.model('form_details')).sendKeys('Lots of detailed text');
      element(by.id('formBtn')).click();
              --> SOME FORM OF ASSERTION FOR HTTP 500 ERROR RESPONSE <
  })
});
```

How do I assert on the response from the server that is received after clicking the button?

NOTE:  I have this sneaking suspicion I don't have the right understanding of the scope of E2E testing that protractor is meant to address... but this feels like something I would need for my E2E testing.  I was writing a test against my POST handler and noticed the server was sending back 500 errors (a bug in the server).  Was hoping protractor could be used to catch these issues.

Comment: Protractor is an e2e testing tool. Your application (under test) should handle the error 500 , for exemple by showing an error message to the user. Your protractor test should verify that the error message is displayed.

Comment: Thanks gontard.  I see what you're saying, but there's always a chance my App Engine app will throw an unexpected exception based on how my Angular client is accessing the service... I could still use my E2E test runs monitoring for this.

Comment: I think I was confused before and I'm *less* confused now :).... If I understand @gontard correctly, he's saying I should be doing some assertion (on a known DOM element?) that describes the HTML error page my app would show if an error happened, not on some state of the protractor/webdriver browser object ( as I was thinking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protractor allows you to access the output of the browser console; you can parse its output and check for errors, like the one a 500 would throw.

Here's an example (not by me) of a similar case:

https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/blob/master/howtos/browserlog/spec.js

If this is faithful to the intended use of Protractor is arguable; like another poster has commented above, you should really display the error in your interface and use Protractor to test such display, not the error itself.